# How to return text from window.prompt() that retains line breaks?

Tags: javascript, string, formatting

I am creating an option on my forum to include external text via a button that will include it formatted into a textarea. I am getting the text via copy and paste into a prompt but the string is returned as one big wall of text, the line breaks are gone. Is there anyway to preserve them or is this an issue with the actual copying of the text?

This is what I have so far:

```
function createExText(textbox) {
    var extext = window.prompt('Enter external text:','');
    var formattedextext = '[extext]'+ extext +'[/extext]';
    insertAtCaret(textbox, formattedextext);
}
```

Comment: What browser are you using? Line breaks are there for me in Chrome 30. Even though when I look at the modal dialog I just see a wall of text, the actual response contains line breaks

Comment: I tested it in FireFox, haven't tried any others yet.

Comment: This does seem to be a Firefox-specific "issue". I say issue in that prompt is really only for one-liners.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know any browser implementation of `prompt` that allows multi-line content. You could create a custom modal implementation with a textarea inside to simulate it.

As @RGraham commented, some browsers like Google Chrome actually preserve the line break characters if you paste an external text into it, however it is shown in only one line inside the dialog. I'd not stick with this solution as it is not user friendly and doesn't seem to work cross browser.

Comment: You can paste multiline text into a prompt, you don't *have* to type to input text

Comment: I tried to paste some multi line text into a prompt using Google Chrome 30 and it removed all the line breaks. Anyway, even if it was allowed, that'd be nothing user friendly.

Comment: Chrome removes line breaks when you look at the input box, but the resulting value is correct. Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FXJfw/). User-friendly or not, Chrome allows multi-line content

Comment: Edited the answer to add your contribution. Thanks. :)

Comment: How would I go about creating a custom modal implementation? I did some searching in but couldn't find much, could you point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: There are several modal plugins out there, jQuery UI is a very popular example (http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form). You can add a form inside it and attach a event when it is submitted to get the prompt data and close it.